# Android: Programmatically created VideoView is showing black screen

Tags: java, android, canvas, android-videoview

So I have a `VideoView` that I have made completely programmatically like so:

```
loadingVideo = new VideoView(getContext());
String videoPath = "android.resource://" + splashActivity.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.loading_video;
loadingVideo.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoPath));
loadingVideo.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(Constants.PIXEL_WIDTH, Constants.PIXEL_HEIGHT));
loadingVideo.setTranslationX(0);
loadingVideo.setTranslationY(0);
loadingVideo.start();
this.widgetContainer.addView(loadingVideo);
```

I know the video is doing something because I later have an `OnCompletionListener` that does go off, the problem is that I don't ever actually see anything and just get a black screen. I draw the method here:

```
if(loadingVideo.isPlaying()) {
    loadingVideo.draw(canvas);
    System.out.println();
}
```

and the `draw(Canvas canvas)` method is refreshed at a rate of 60fps using this:

```
Canvas canvas = null;
SurfaceHolder sh = getHolder();
boolean unlocked = false;
try {
    if(sh.getSurface().isValid()) {
        canvas = sh.lockCanvas();
        synchronized(sh) {
            draw(canvas);
        }
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    if(canvas != null && sh.getSurface().isValid()) {
        sh.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        unlocked = true;
    }
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(!unlocked && canvas != null && sh.getSurface().isValid()) {
        sh.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it isn't drawing or what I'm doing wrong.

Side note: I know that the way I'm doing this seems odd but I know it works because I've created other views this way in other projects and they've worked fine. I just can't get the video to show anything other than a black screen.

Comment: videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);//this line solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
loadingVideo.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```

> before the

```
loadingVideo.start();
```